# How disable blinking cursor in gnome-shell's terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, cursor, gnome-shell

Using gnome-shell, I want to disable the blinking cursor in the default Terminal. Yet cannot find anything in its profile setting to toggle the behavior.

How can I achieve that? I prefer a one-liner.

Comment: Beginning with gnome-terminal 3.28 (which will be shipped  by Ubuntu 18.04), there's a graphical setting for this.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by this [blog post](https://geoff.greer.fm/2016/08/26/gnome-terminal-cursor-blinking-saga/), you can disable the blinking cursor through a subshell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')/ cursor-blink-mode off
```